# vue-tables-2 emit page number to parent component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vue-tables-2

I've been trying to find a way of getting the page number from vue-tables-2 but I couldn't figure it out. My best guess was with Vuex but I couldn't get it to work either. I just find the documentation very briefed and not detailed enough for newbies to Vue like me.

Is there anyone who managed to get it working or at least a similar tutorial.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue tables 2 has a `vue-tables.pagination` custom event which is fired on page change. You can use it to track the current page.

Alternatively you can dive into the instance itself (If you are not using vuex) and fetch the `Page` data property (E.g `this.$refs.myTable.Page`)